# Web page doesn't load in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

I have a problem with my website: http://axli.net/larrea

When I refresh chrome, the page doesn't load correctly, while in other browsers (safari, firefox, chrome canary) it loads correctly. Instead, if I click at any link of the website, the page loads perfectly. It seems like the css is not displaying.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: it actually seems completely fine

Comment: loads fine for me as well. Chrome 33 on OS X. Maybe make sure your cache is clear?

Comment: it is fine for me too Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 Apple - OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush DNS cache:

1. through Chrome: **chrome://net-internals/#dns** click on button "**Clear host cache**"
2. If (1) doesn't solve issue use CMD command (Windows only): **ipconfig /flushdns**

Answer (score 0):

It loads fine on my chrome browsers too. Tried on v28, 29, 30, ... upto v33.
What chrome version are you using?

Things you could do to troubleshoot this are:

1. Check if an extension is blocking access. Maybe **adblock** or **proxy extension** or even **DNS settings** on your browser.
2. Check if you internet connection is slow.
3. Run the page in incognito
4. Check console log for any errors.

Let us know what happens when you tried these steps.